# Is it possible to obtain a replacement part for a collectible minifigure?

Tags: minifigures, replacement-parts, collectable-minifigures

My son's latest collectible minifigure purchase was missing its legs.  Is it possible to get a replacement set of legs?

Comment: I had a part missing from a brand new Cars lego set (old set but bought brand new at retail and unopened). Lego wouldnt provide the missing part as they said they no longer produced it. I eventually managed to find the part on eBay (albeit second hand and not cheap, although mint condition)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, yes it is possible.

The best place to find replacement parts is [Bricklink.com](http://www.bricklink.com).

You don't mention which minifgure is missing its leg, but for example, [here](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=970c00pb099) is a link to the 'Hips and Legs with Studded Belt and Safety Pins Pattern' of the Series 4 minifg 'Punk Rocker'.

To find the required part for your minifig, a good starting point would be to look thorough the [Collectible Minifigures Catalog Gallery](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catID=746) on Bricklink and go from there.

As for cost, it varies greatly on based on rarity and desirability of the part you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

LEGO will replace a part for free on their [website](http://service.lego.com/en-gb/replacementparts/), providing it was missing from purchase. Sadly replacement parts aren't available for Collectible Minifigures, but you can contact them to let them know.

Ensure the Minifigure packet has been fully emptied, it's quite easy to lose parts when you open the packet.

Comment: +1, Lego is very good about providing replacement parts for pieces that were missing from a newly purchased set.

Comment: @JW8 True, but I did try using a set ID from one of the minifigure packets on the part replacement site but they don't do replacement parts for them.

Comment: got it - I've never replaced parts from the minifig packs before, only the usual sets.

Comment: While they don't replace specific parts for CMF (because of the nature of their production), they may offer to send you a new mystery pack. You may not get the same figure, but the next one should be complete.