# Known quality control issue with 10234 Sydney Opera House?

Tags: sets, architecture

I have just completed 10234 Sydney Opera House, with one white half-shell (Bricklink: 41749 White Wedge 8x3x2 Open Right) missing.

Both the Bricklink inventory and the Lego instructions show 34 of 41749 and 35 of 41750, so this looks unusual.

Have I misplaced an element, or is this a known quality control issue with this set?

Comment: There should be information on what to do in case of missing pieces at the end of the booklet

Comment: I can't speak to quality control on this specific set, but if you ever find your set is missing pieces, you can easily get them replaced free of charge at https://service.lego.com/en-us/replacementparts#BasicInfo

Comment: Rather similar to the other [questions on missing parts](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1676/56)...

Comment: In six years of collecting vigorously I've had missing parts, wrong parts, miscolored parts, broken parts. As your collection is growing, you will inevitably bump into these issues. Not a biggie. TLG's support is spectacular, and there's an easy-to-use form on their website just for such cases.

Comment: Yes after years of collecting I have seen a few extra/missing parts.  The same opera house also needed a few plates and a telescope that I had to take from my existing stock.  I was wondering about the 35 left-sided/34 right-sided pieces on what should be a symmetrical build.  I will read through the instructions again to see if my mirrored-building technique with opposite sides has confused me.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to imply you built some of the structures symmetrically; however, by looking at the building instructions, I notice they are not: the subpart starting at page 37 of book 3 uses 7 wedges in total, while the opposite one on page 48 uses only 6.

While missing parts do happen (and are usually solved very diligently by the customer service, as said in other questions on the subject), it's always worth double-checking if the instructions were followed correctly, especially in such a huge model.